# Delete K nodes in a linked list having their data less than the next node's

Tags: c++, linked-list

The question is from [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/zh/practice/data-structures/linked-list/singly-linked-list/practice-problems/algorithm/remove-friends-5/).

> Given two numbers N and K where N is the number of nodes and K is the number of nodes to be deleted, delete K nodes whose data is less than their next node's data. If no such nodes exist, delete the last node.

But it is still giving me TLE. I tried all the optimisations that could occur to me. I know this can be done with stacks but I would like to know if it can't done in the allocated time with linked lists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

void addnode(struct Node** head, struct Node** tail, int data)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->value = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    if( *head == nullptr)
    {
        *head = temp;
        *tail = *head;
        return;
    }
    (*tail)->next = temp;
    *tail = temp;
}

void deleteNode(struct Node** head, struct Node** prev, struct Node** temp)
{
    if( (*prev)->next == *head)
    {
        *head = (*prev)->next->next;
        return;
    }
    (*prev)->next = (*temp)->next;
}

void deletenodeatlast(struct Node** prev)
{
    (*prev)->next = (*prev)->next->next; 
}

void display(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* p = head;
    while(p != nullptr)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--)
    {
        struct Node* head = nullptr;
        struct Node* tail = head;
        int N, K;
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &K);

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int data;
            scanf("%d", &data);
            addnode(&head, &tail, data);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        {
            bool isGreater = false;
            struct Node* p = head;
            struct Node* prev = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            prev->value = 1000000;
            prev->next = p;

            while( p->next != nullptr)
            {
                if( p->value < p->next->value)
                {
                    deleteNode(&head, &prev, &p);
                    isGreater = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = p;
                    p = p->next;
                }

                if( isGreater )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( !isGreater)
            {
                deletenodeatlast(&prev);
            }
        }
        display(head);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want this reviewed as pure C (which is how you wrote the code), or C++ (which is how you tagged it)? Because, as C++, a review amounts to a full re-write.

Comment: @Frank I have used some attributes of C++ such as nullptr and bool data type.   I would like it to be reviewed as C++.

Comment: `bool` is also in C99.

Comment: Notice that you don't need the list. You may work directly on the input stream, with \$O(1)\$ space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [Shlemiel The Painter](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter)?
He never moves his paint can, and so repeatedly walks all over the town.

What you need to do is take the algorithm for removing one friend, look at how it works when applied `k` times, and then cut out all the redundant Setup work.

---

Aside from that, you aren't using any C++ containers or algorithms, nor smart-pointers (`std::unique_ptr`), `new` or the like.

Don't assume nothing will go wrong. While it is unlikely with `malloc()` as long as you stay reasonable, `scanf()` parses user-input, and users will do everything possible, even if you think it's impossible.

There's more, but that should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

### Initialize your variables:

Leaving variables in uninitialized states is generally a bad idea, get into the habit of always giving them a value:

```
int T = 0;
```

The small additional amount of work required will soon become second nature, and in the long run, the bugs prevented by having that reflex are well worth the trouble. The successors to C++ (Rust and D) make you jump through hoops to create uninitialized variables for that very reason.

### Do not use scanf(), it's a pure C function, use std::cin instead

```
int T = 0;
std::cin >> T
```

### Use the standard data structures

All of your node insert/remove code is already provided by the STL under `std::list<>`. You should use that instead, it's way safer.

To give you an idea, your code as written has memory leaks all over the place, `std::list<>` takes care of all your memory management, so you don't have to worry about it.

It's also guaranteed to work, unlike your code which appears to get you stuck in an infinite loop.

Speaking of memory management:

### do not use malloc, use new instead

It's not just that new is better, the following line leads to invalid C++ code.

```
struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

There is no `Node` object created, ever, all you are doing is interpreting raw memory as if it was a `Node` object, which is a violation of the language, **even if it works**.

### Be consistent!

```
while(T--)
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

When you don't need the index, both of these are valid ways of iterating N times, but you should stick to one approach, and not randomly mix-and-match.